# Is it must to add page in admin first to create custom page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom html. I am using WordPress and I want to create page for login.

Is it necessary to first add static login page then  create page template and then choose it from page template dropdown?

Also, I am trying it with template_redirect action hook like below code and it also works but i think the code is not optimized. I am looking for some standard method for this.

I have many pages that I need to create. So, is it good to choose this method?

Also, for each page i have to identify if this page is suppose login page then i want to perform specific task. So, what is the best way to do this? I am right now using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for this, but it also gives problem, because i am working in localhost. So, suppose my site url is `http://localhost/sitename`, then for `http://localhost/mysite/login`, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/mysite/login`. So, it will create problem in my live domain too.

```
<?php 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse131387_template_redirect' );
function wpse131387_template_redirect( ){
    call_page('join-us','login.php');
}

function call_page($uri,$page_name){
    if(is_ssl())
    {
        $protocol = 'https://';
    }
    else
    {
        $protocol = 'http://';
    }
    $page_url = $protocol.$_SERVER['HTTPS'].$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($page_url == get_site_url().'/'.$uri) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->is_404 = false;
        status_header(200);
        include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/'.$page_name);
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Can anyone suggest me the better way to create custom template? Is it must to add page in admin first? And when this login page loads, how can I  identify this is login page or not? Is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is good way in localhost subdirectory?

Comment: What's wrong with the built in login page at /wp-login ?

Answer (score 0):

For login page specifically Wordpress has a page where you can get an idea of how to customize .

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form

For other pages, it totally depends on what you are requirements are. There is no harm in creating pages and then creating templates for them. If you have some supporting pages like http://localhost/sitename/profile/edit?id=100, you can use query vars and template_redirect.